# I need good tool for database unit testing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, testing

I've tried to test SQL Server database stored procedures (write tests like unit) using Visual Studio 2010 testing tool but it is very inconvenient.
Is there any another more convenient tool for testing database stored procedures?

Comment: I'm curious to know how you got on with SQL unit testing. Did you get it in place, and did it prove useful?

Comment: I found TSQLUnit, proposed by Paul very simple and useful tool. This provides important functional for unit testing. My application has business, placed on database layer in form of stored procedures and unit testing is absolutely necessary. Try TSQLUnit, it is very simple to use.

Comment: I'd be interested to get your views on the tsqlt.org framework, as this is a tool we're planning to support here at Red Gate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out [TSQLUnit](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/tsqlunit/) for an open source, SQL Server unit testing app. And there are several more SQL Server-specific testing apps [listed on this page.](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/unit_sql.php)

Answer (score 1):

We are using NUnit, and wrote our own library in C#. Works really well for us, and here are some articles where we have described the approach: [Close these Loopholes - Reproduce Database Errors](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/close-these-loopholes---reproduce-database-errors/)